# display page variables in google analytics user flow

Tags: google-analytics, webforms

is it possible to display page variables in google analytics user flow?
in product page, products are displayed based on PID variable.
I want to know which products are displayed by user ?

Comment: Do you mean the google analytics website?

Comment: yes, google analytics website

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/